# Update multiple columns in MySQL using the same WHERE clause

Tags: mysql

I just want to update 3 columns in my MySQL database with the same WHERE clause. I have a requirement where in there are these 3 columns namely aug, sep, december which have a value greater than 10000. So if I have a value greater than 10000 in all the three columns, I want to update them with the value -1. Please find below some sample data

[Sample data exported as CSV from MySQL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EYVC.png)

I don't know how to get them in one single query. I tried the following query and there is an error. Please help

```
UPDATE climatedata set aug=-1, sep = -1, december=-1 WHERE aug>10000,sep>10000,december>10000;
```

My requirement is I would like to update aug, sep, december column having value greater than 10000 to -1 in a single query. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please refer to SQL syntax for where conditions with multiple clauses - https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp. Here is the updated query.

```
UPDATE climatedata set aug=-1, sep = -1, december=-1 WHERE aug>10000 AND sep>10000 AND december>10000;
```

Comment: Oh so stupid of me! Thanks a lot @Kishore Kirdat for pointing it out. I can't upvote your answer, since I don't have the reputation but +1 for your answer.